# Can I make an int value in an array have attributes?

Tags: python

I tried with a class, but im used to ruby coding, so I mess it up a bunch
so far, ive tried: `setattr(array[0],'cap',i)`

Comment: could be better achieved with an array of dicts.

Comment: dicts? im a noob at py so...

Comment: Here's what it would look like: `[ { 'val' : 100,'cap' : 200 } , { 'val' : 101,'cap':201} ]`

Comment: You tried with a class, but you do not know what dicts are? You should start from the beginning, not from the back.

Comment: as I said before: im used to ruby, and thats how i know classes

Answer (score 3):

No, ints can’t have attributes. You would need to change the type of the value:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class IntWithCap:
    value: int
    cap: int

array = [IntWithCap(42, cap=i)]
```

(example is a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), but it could be a regular class, a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), a dict, or even a type inheriting from `int`… although that’s rarely, if ever, the right choice. pick better names as appropriate)

Or store the associated values somewhere else:

```
array = [42]
array_caps = [0]
```